# How to make TypeScript error when using .finally() on a Promise

Tags: typescript

I'm using Google Cloud Functions on Node 8 which doesn't support .finally() and sometimes I forget and deploy code with .finally().

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I've tried adding `"lib": ["ES2017", "ES2015.Promise"],` to the above config, but that didn't work. If I "go to definition" of .finally() in vscode it takes me to an es2018 type definition, which it seems like it shouldn't if I want ES2017.
[image]

How can I get TypeScript to catch this so I don't deploy code that will fail at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types for `Promise.finally` are likely being included by the version of `@types/node`.

---

If your project relies on node typings, you should ensure that the version of `@types/node` being pulled in matches the version of node that you're expecting.  `npm i @types/node@8.x` will install a version of `@types/node` that doesn't include `Promise#finally`.

---

If your project doesn't intentionally rely on node typings, there's a good chance they're being included due to some dependency.  The default behavior of Typescript is to include any "global" types that are found in `node_modules/@types` packages, which means `@types/node` will be included if you install any package that depends on `@types/node`.

You can fix this by adding `types: []` to tsconfig's compiler options.  This will prevent TS from including "global" types from `node_modules/@types`, but will still include module types when you import the corresponding module.  (e.g. `import foo from "foo"` will still use `@types/foo`)  You can explicitly specify any global type packages to include in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the type of `Promise.finally` by writing an interface:

```js
interface Promise<T> {
    finally: undefined
}

let p: Promise<number> = new Promise(() => 5);

// Error: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.(2722)
p.finally(() => {});
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYFtgGcIA8AKgHzIDeAUMjcjKHADaMCeAXMgK4gAmE9ICD0oBfSpUYQwyAA4d02PIRCcsAI2hkAvMkEB3NJhz4AFCYCUyLWQCs5gNyUZAOgFNWZy9YoiHQA)